# How to use IKVM with java 1.8?

Tags: java, c#, .net, visual-studio, ikvm

Not able to convert java jar 1.8v with ikvm

I tried running jar compiled with 1.7v java for ikvm(7.2) it runs perfectly well and converts my jar to dll.

But i am not able to find suitable ikvm version which will run for java1.8 jar as i am getting class52 error

Can anyone share from where to download ikvm package for 1.8 as i see in the official page there are too many core, net files which does not have ikvm.exe as i need to run it from command prompt using ikvmc command.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly speaking I am new to this and I also looked for a solution how to build from the command prompt.
But I think they changed the way it worked previously, currently it is per the  [Usage](https://IKVM-8.2.3-tools-ikvm-net461.zip) section on GitHub (and the same description is on the [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/IKVM#readme-body-tab) site).
As I understand, all IKVM 8 versions implement Java 8, so I looked into previous versions, and **8.2.3**'s **IKVM-8.2.3-tools-ikvm-net461.zip** has ikvm.exe. I can't try it out nowadays however.
Could you give a feedback after you solved it, then how?

Answer (score 0):

You install the IKVM Nuget package, or the IKVM.Maven.Sdk NuGet package, and add a reference to your JAR or Maven library. As the README file instructs.

https://github.com/ikvmnet/ikvm#readme